# invoke variable declared in child script to parent shell script

Tags: shell, variables, global

in my case script A is calling to script B.

now I am declaring a variable in my child script B and would like to do if else condition check in prent script.

variablename in child script

```
logFileName=stop_log$current_date'.log'
```

this is how I am trying to invoke

```
logFileName = os.environ["logFileName"]  
export logfilename
echo $logFileName
```

and then doing condition check like

```
if
logerr=`grep 'ConnectException' $logFileName`
if [ -z "$logerr" ]; then
echo " No error "
else
exit 1
fi
```

I am not able to exort that variable in parent script. could someone please help.

Comment: could someone please help me on this..

Comment: Did this help you solve your problem? if so you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A child process, for all practical purposes, cannot set a variable in the parent process.

Therefore, you have a few options available to get the log file name from the child to the parent:

1. Use the `.` command (aka `source` in C shell and Bash) to read script B and execute it as part of the current shell.
2. Have script B echo the name of the logfile. Script A can capture it using:

   ```
   logfilename=$(script-b …)
   ```

   The major downside of this is that it is hard to do if script B is supposed to generate other output too.
3. Have script B save the name of the logfile in another file.  Usually, script A should tell script B where to save it.  Occasionally, you can agree on a location, but remember that there could be multiple copies of the scripts running at the same time, so a fixed name (`/tmp/tmp.file` for example) is dangerous on multiple counts (security and concurrency are both issues).

---

### Illustrating option 3

#### Script-A

```
logfilename=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/Script-A.log.XXXXXX

trap "rm -f $logfilename; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

echo "Message from Script-A" > $logfilename

Script-B $logfilename

echo "End message from Script-A" >> $logfilename

echo Log file name: $logfilename
cat $logfilename

rm -f $logfilename
trap 0
```

#### Script-B

```
logfilename=${1:?}

echo "Script-B busy at work"
echo "Message for the log file" >> $logfilename  # NB: >> each time

echo "Script-B wrapping up"
echo "Script-B complete" >> $logfilename
```

In the code of `Script-A`, the command `mktemp` creates a temporary file name at random based on the template given.  Normally, the template will be `/tmp/script-A.log.XXXXXX`, where the 6 X's will be replaced by random letters or digits.  The `trap` command means that if the script is signalled (SIGHUP 1, SIGINT 2, SIGQUIT 3, SIGPIPE 13 or SIGTERM 15) or exits (0), the temporary file will be removed.  If it is meant to outlive the run of `Script-A`, you would omit the trap but echo the name.  It writes a message to the log file; it runs Script-B, passing the log file name; it writes another message.  It then wraps up: reports the file name, shows its contents; removes the file; and cancels the trap so that it can exit with a status of 0, success.

The `Script-B` code checks that it was given an argument (`${1:?}`) and saves it as the variable `logfilename`.  You could have had `Script-A` export the variable and `Script-B` could have tested that the environment variable was set instead of requiring an argument, but arguments are generally better.  Then `Script-B` echoes a message to its output and another to the log file (note that you need to append to the log file).  It does its work (nothing here); writes another message to output and another message to the logfile; and exits.

There are lots of other stunts you can pull in Script-B to get the messages to the log file, but this should get you going.

If you don't have the `mktemp` command, either get its source (GNU or BSD), or use:

```
logfilename=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/Script-A.log.$$
```

This uses the process ID to give you moderate assurance that the name won't be used by another process, but it is more easily determined and so is less secure than the random name generated by `mktemp`.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion. could you please provide me some demo example of option 2. I am not clear on how to have this setup

Comment: as you suggested, with option 2, its not working for as we have multiple echo statement in child script.

Comment: if you could tell me some easy way by which I can declare that variable in parent script and call in child script, that also work for me